# Runtime.getRuntime().exec() in loops

Tags: java, loops, ffmpeg, runtime, exec

I'm writing a little tool to create some thumbnails in java automatically.

therefor I execute `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);` in a `for`-loop.
Now my Problem is, that only the first thumbnail gets created.

My code so far:

```
public static void testFFMpeg(File videoFile) throws IOException {
    FFMpegWrapper wraper = new FFMpegWrapper(videoFile);
    int length = (int) wraper.getInputDuration() / 1000;
    String absolutePath = videoFile.getAbsolutePath();
    String path = absolutePath.substring(0, absolutePath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    int c = 1;
    System.out.println(path + "thumb_" + c + ".png");
    for (int i = 1; i <= length; i = i + 10) {
        int h = i / 3600;
        int m = i / 60;
        int s = i % 60;
        String command = "ffmpeg -i " + absolutePath + " -ss " + h + ":" + m + ":" + s + " -vframes 1 " + path
            + "thumb_" + c + "_" + videoFile.getName() + ".png";
        System.out.println(command);
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        c++;
    }
}
```

the output is:

```
ffmpeg -i /mnt/Speicherschwein/workspace/testVideos/Roentgen_A_VisarioG2_005.avi -ss 0:0:1 -vframes 1 /mnt/Speicherschwein/workspace/testVideos/thumb_1_Roentgen_A_VisarioG2_005.avi.png
ffmpeg -i /mnt/Speicherschwein/workspace/testVideos/Roentgen_A_VisarioG2_005.avi -ss 0:0:11 -vframes 1 /mnt/Speicherschwein/workspace/testVideos/thumb_2_Roentgen_A_VisarioG2_005.avi.png
ffmpeg -i /mnt/Speicherschwein/workspace/testVideos/Roentgen_A_VisarioG2_005.avi -ss 0:0:21 -vframes 1 /mnt/Speicherschwein/workspace/testVideos/thumb_3_Roentgen_A_VisarioG2_005.avi.png
```

so the loop is running fine and the command is also fine, if I run it manually from command-line its creating each thumbnail, so there seems to be a problem, that in the 2. call of `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);` it don't get started cause the first run isn't finished yet.

S is there possibility to pause the thread or something like that until the command run by `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);` is frinished?

Comment: Check the process class in java, it has methods waitFor() that will solve your purpose.

Comment: 1. Use `ProcessBuilder`; 2. Break down the command and each parameter into it's own `String` element, which can passed to `ProcessBuilder`, this really helps with keeping things clean and supports paths with spaces; 3. Read the `Process` `OutputStream` (and error stream); 4. Use `Process#waitFor` and check the exit value;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Runtime.exec` returns a `Process` instance, which you can use to monitor the status.

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
boolean finished = process.waitFor(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

That last line can be put into a loop, or just set a reasonable timeout.

Comment: This solves the problem for me.
I tried to use `ProcessBuilder` but I always got an exception "ERROR-2: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden!".

Comment: Do you have a link to the `waitFor` method?  The only one I can find is [`int waitFor()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#waitFor())

Comment: It was introduced in Java 8 -https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#waitFor-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-

Answer (score 0):

Because you currently run it in one thread, try to open a new thread each time you exec command. And join thread after you finish the process create thumbnail.